# Depending on table.Tablename

Tags: c#, for-loop, datatable, dataset

I want to run a `loop` if the relevant table is called `table1` or `table2`. Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
foreach (DataTable table in DtSet.Tables)
{
    if ((table.TableName == "table1")||(table.TableName == "table2"))
    {
        foreach (DataRow sourceRow in table.Rows)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to modify this code so that the name check is done without having to loop through the whole dataset?
Many thanks.

Comment: This reminds me [Introducing the for-if anti-pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/12/27/10251210.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like....

```
ProcessTableData(DtSet.Tables["table1"]);
ProcessTableData(DtSet.Tables["table2"]);    


void ProcessTableData(DataTable dataTable)
{
    if (dataTable == null)
        return;

    foreach (DataRow sourceRow in dataTable.Rows)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `TableName` using [indexers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58st33fb.aspx) that accept table name as parameter. Indexers still use loop internally.

```
var table1 = dtSet.Tables["table1"];
var table2 = dtSet.Tables["table2"];

if (table1 != null)
{
    DoOperation(table1);
}

if (table2 != null)
{
    DoOperation(table2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may loop over two names (instead of looping over all tables), and for each name, try getting a table from `DtSet.Tables` by name.

Answer (score 0):

Use contains:

```
  if ((table.TableName.Contains("table1"))||(table.TableName.Contains("table2"))) 
{
    foreach (DataRow sourceRow in table.Rows) 
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write

```
if ((DtSet.Tables.Contains("table1")
{
    foreach (DataRow sourceRow in DtSet.Tables["table1"])
    {
    }
}
```

it will still have a loop inside. but will be cleaner.

doing it without loop at all is impossible.